# How to create Checkbuttons with images and text?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, tkinter, checkbox

I am just getting started with `tkinter` widgets and am trying to create `Checkbuttons` with both images and text labels.  Unfortunately, this cannot be done with basic `Checkbutton(master=, image=, text=)` as setting the `image` suppresses the `text`.

Here's a silly yet reproducible example of what I'm trying to do.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Checkbutton, Label
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import requests

def getImgFromUrl(url): # using solution from : https://stackoverflow.com/a/18369957/2573061
   try:
       r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
       pilImage = Image.open(r.raw)
       phoImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pilImage)
       return phoImage
   except Exception as e:
       print('Error ' + repr(e) )
       return None


class AnimalPicker(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()        
    
    def initUI(self):
        self.master.title("Animal Picker")

        
def main(): 
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("250x450+300+300")
    app = AnimalPicker()
    
    imageUrls = ['http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/martin-berube/flat-animal/64/dachshund-icon.png',
             'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconka/meow/64/cat-walk-icon.png',
             'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/sonya/swarm/64/Unicorn-icon.png']

    labels = ['Dog','Cat','Unicorn']
    
    images = [getImgFromUrl(x) for x in imageUrls]
    
    for i in range(len(images)):
        cb = Checkbutton(root, text=labels[i], image = images[i])
        cb.pack(anchor = 'w', padx=5,pady=5) 
    root.mainloop()  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Gives me:

[image]

But I would like to have the labels "Cat", "Dog", and "Unicorn" either underneath or to the side of the images.

It's also important that the solution work for an arbitrary number of `Checkbuttons`, as in the `for` loop above.

Should I be using Grid and stacking these `Checkbuttons` next to `Labels`?  I've managed to avoid learning it so far.  Or is it easy to do with `Pack`?

Comment: _" Unfortunately, this cannot be done with basic Checkbutton(..., image= , text= ) as setting the image suppresses the text."_ - read up on the `compound` option.

Comment: @Bryan Doh - well, that was easy -- the answer is yours if you want it!

Comment: Also, a bad workaround would be to define a new class inheriting from frame including checkbutton + label + label.

Comment: This question could use better titling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *I would like to have the labels ("Cat", "Dog", "Unicorn") either underneath or to the side of the images.*

As suggested in [Bryan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48085771/label-an-arbitrary-number-of-tkinter-widgets#comment83146501_48085771), this can be done by configuring `compound` option of `Checkbutton`.

Simply replace:

```
cb = Checkbutton(root, text=labels[i], image = images[i])
```

with:

```
cb = Checkbutton(root, text=labels[i], image = images[i], compound='left')
```

or set [`compound` option](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm#Tkinter.Label.config-method) to *an element* of `['bottom', 'center', 'left', 'right', 'top']` which is by default `None`:

```
cb['compound'] = 'top'
```

---

Below example produces an example for most Windows users:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()

mypath = r"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Koala.jpg"
img = Image.open(mypath)
glb_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
tk.Checkbutton(root, text="Koala", image=glb_img, compound='top').pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

Also it's worth noting that importing `PIL` is redundant for `.png` format, one could use either `tk.PhotoImage(data=image_data)` or `tk.PhotoImage(file=image_file)`.

Comment: Yeah, it was kind of a trivial question, but in my defense the `tkinter` docs showing in Google results  are surprisingly not helpful.  E.g., the same book you link to, in the [Checkbutton](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/checkbutton.htm#reference) page, doesn't list the non-default arguments to the option.  The entry `help(Checkbutton)` is too long to read in my IDE -- trying to figure out how to paginate it.

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 Yeah, I've read label's explanation on `compound` instead.