# Error message "couldn't recognize data in image file" when trying to import a ".ppm" image using tkinter

Tags: python, image, tkinter, canvas

I am trying to import a photo into a canvas that I made with "tkinter". I used this line of coad to load it: `img = PhotoImage(file="image1.ppm")` but then I get the error it can't recognize the data. Why is this happening? When I download an image as a ppm. file it automaticly gets stored as a "gimp" file. Is this where the problem occours?

Comment: I think that `tkinter.PhotoImage` doesn't recognise the `.ppm` format. Try using `PIL` to open the image then use `PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage` to convert it into an tkinter image. For more info on how to use `PIL` with `tkinter` read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18369957/11106801)

Comment: ppm works with tkinter.PhotoImage, i am using it