# How to embed image file (jpeg or png) onto a figure canvas in tkinter root window?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm writing a GUI using tkinter, and at startup of the script I want the root window to display a canvas comprised of a simple image file (preferably jpeg or png). Here's my attempt thus far:

```
from tkinter import Tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

root = Tk()
root.wm_title("My Window")
root.geometry('1500x1000')
root.configure(bg='lightgrey')

background = mpimg.imread('background.png')
fig=plt.imshow(background)
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP)
```

This yields the error message, "AttributeError: 'AxesImage' object has no attribute 'set_canvas'" which I don't understand how to interpret. I've tried experimenting with tkinter's PhotoImage, that produces a similar error.

Comment: could You show the whole error? because in Your code there is neither `AxesImage` nor `set_canvas`

Comment: Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18369957/11106801)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fig` is not matplotlib `Figure` object.  You need to create an instance of `Figure()` and use it to hold the image:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

background = plt.imread('background.png')
ax.imshow(background)

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP)
```