# Exception has occurred: TclError

Tags: python, image, tkinter

i want to display image and set image size according to label size.

```
img = Image.open("filepath")
img = img.resize((34, 26), Image.ANTIALIAS)


Label(master, image=img).place(x=20,y=10,width=80,height=80)
```

However this error message appears.

```
Exception has occurred: TclError
image "<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGBA size=34x26 at 0x20B9C0199D0>" doesn't exist
```

Comment: You need to save the Image and open it with ```ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=...)```

Comment: You need to first convert the image to a `PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage` object. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18369957/11106801) for more info.

Comment: @Sujay Saving it then opening it like that is a waste of time. You can directly pass the `PIL.Image.Image` object in to `PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(...)` as the first argument.

Comment: I'm still confused in the implementation, can you show me the correct code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()

img = Image.open("cards.png")
img = img.resize((34, 26), Image.ANTIALIAS)
tk_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

label = tk.Label(root, image=tk_img)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

All of your code is right but in order to pass it in to `tkinter`, you need to make it into a `ImageTk.PhotoImage` object by using `tk_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)`

Comment: @gdf14 Also keep in mind, `png` images can be directly showed with `tk.PhotoImage`, instead of using `PIL`, but that would mean you have to save the image(cannot be used in this case). Just a tip for the future.